# increasing mysql table open cache?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I often read that it is best to increase this variable slowly. Can someone explain why? My status indicates that I should increase it... What is best practice / "slowly"?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this all InnoDB ???

Comment: primarily 370+ innodb tables, 4 myisam

Comment: Do you have innodb_file_per_table enabled ???

Comment: To be honest, I increased the value fairly fast and aggressively. We would get stalls when the `Open_tables` value hit `table_open_cache` and the server would stall and flush out a bunch of tables. I just doubled the value until we stopped getting the stalls. We're also 100% innodb, so this variable still matters even with `innodb_open_files` being tweaked

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using InnoDB with [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, you need to raise [**innodb_open_files**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_open_files) because this dictates the number of open file handles on `.ibd` files.

In MySQL 5.6, this setting is treated a little different.

> > This variable is relevant only if you use multiple InnoDB tablespaces. It specifies the maximum number of .ibd files that MySQL
> >     can keep open at one time. The minimum value is 10. As of MySQL 5.6.6,
> >     the default value is 300 if innodb_file_per_table is not enabled, and
> >     the higher of 300 and table_open_cache otherwise. Before 5.6.6, the
> >     default value is 300.
> >
> > The file descriptors used for .ibd files are for InnoDB tables only. They are independent of those specified by the --open-files-limit
> >     server option, and do not affect the operation of the table cache. For
> >     general I/O tuning advice, see Section 8.5.7, “Optimizing InnoDB Disk
> >     I/O”.

Here is an [**additional reference from MySQL Performance Blog**](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/11/18/how-innodb_open_files-affects-performance/) about setting innodb_open_files.

Raising [**innodb_open_files**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_open_files) to a big number should not be that all that troublesome, but please be sensible about the number you choose.

Comment: RDS seems to have a ceiling here of 300 for innodb_open_files. how annoying-- oh i guess it takes the larger value (read your answer more closely) thanks! for 5.5?

Comment: The excerpt above is for MySQL 5.6, not 5.5. The default would be 300 for 5.5 : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_open_files .

Comment: Opened_files status is increasing quickly, which would indicate that I need to increase one of these values. The open_tables status is only 595... I wonder if you may have had this experience with RDS?