# Error log "[Warning] InnoDB: innodb_open_files=10 is exceeded (10) files stay open)"

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu, error-log

I just created a new Digital Ocean VPS, and when looking at my log file it gives me this warning. I'm running a wordpress site.

Any ideas what this is? Do I need to increase this, and by how much?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [increasing mysql table open cache?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39527/increasing-mysql-table-open-cache)

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_open_files = 10` is much too small.  300 is the default and I have not seen anyone set it lower than 300.

Go to the config settings (see D.O. for how to do that) and change it to 20; see that suffices.  If it still complains, keep raising it.

How much RAM is allocated to your MySQL?  Maybe you have a 'tiny' allocation, thereby indicating that this setting (and others) should not be raised 'too much'.